# How to connect rows from different tables

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html-table

I have two tables and I need to allow the user to connect rows from one table with rows from another, such as:

---

[image]

and later when the user clicks on submit button, I need the information about those connections in such a way:

---

```
[ 
  {left: "Pera Lozac", right: "Eve Jakson"},  
  {left: "Mika Mikic", right: "Jill Smmith"},  
  {left: "Zika Zivac", right: "Joh Doe"},  
  {left: "Dezurni Krivac", right: "Joh Doe"},  
]
```

> How should I go about this using `HTML/Javascript` ?

Comment: There is one library named splumb https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ which is powerful when it comes to "connecting" things, but only the basic variant is for free but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: @axel.michel, thaks but this to expensive for me. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my snippet below

> **Usage :** `select(click)` any number of rows from the left table and select one row from the right table, then click Add Connection, the connection is then added and displayed below on the page in the form of a javascript object.

*Note :* Selected rows are highlighted in grey and the highlighting is removed when that row is unselected.

**Snippet**

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp_color = '#dddddd';
  $('tr').on('click', function() {
    current_background = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).css('background-color', temp_color);
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
    }
  });
  $('#add_conn').on('click', function() {
    var left = [];
    var right = [];
    $('tr').filter(function() {
      var match = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
      var this_element = $(this).css('background-color');
      if (hexc(this_element) != hexc(match)) {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var count = 0;
        var string_test = "";
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
          if (count < 2) {
            string_test += " " + $(this).text();
          }
          count++;
        });
        if ($(this).closest('div').attr('id') == "one") {
          left.push(string_test.trim());
        } else if ($(this).closest('div').attr('id') == "two") {
          right.push(string_test.trim());
        }
      }
    });
    var temp = $('#message').html();
    var arr = [];
    for (l = 0; l < left.length; l++) {
      arr.push({
        left: left[l],
        right: right[0]
      });
    }
    temp = temp + JSON.stringify(arr);
    $('#message').html(temp);
  });

});

function hexc(colorval) {
  var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
  delete(parts[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
    if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
  }
  color = '#' + parts.join('');
  return color;
}
```

```css
#one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 1%;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 35%;
}
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
tr {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}
body:not(.nohover) tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
.selected-bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.selected-bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}
#message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="add_conn" value="Add This Connection" />
<div id="one">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Pera</td>
      <td>Lozac</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mika</td>
      <td>Mikic</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zika</td>
      <td>Zivac</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dezurni</td>
      <td>Krivac</td>
      <td>44</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div id="two">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div id="message">

</div>
```

Check this working sample here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/rw6joaj8/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pretty acceptable for solution b. And without solution A B takes precedence. So accepted, Thanks.